# unidentified reference issue when having .h and .cpp files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am trying to have .h and .cpp files in my ros package. All my code is in the src file and I have the following code. The code works fine when I run through xcode so the syntax is okay however ros does not like it for some unknown reason: Here is the .h file

```
#include <iostream>
class DroneCommands{

public:

DroneCommands();
void Land(int time);



 };
  #endif /* defined(__helloworld__DroneCommands__) */
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "DroneCommands.h"
#include <iostream>


DroneCommands::DroneCommands(){
std::cout << "object created" << std::endl;
}




void DroneCommands::Land(int time){
std::cout << "Landing!!" << std::endl;

}
```

Finally, here is main.cpp:
#include 
#include "DroneCommands.h"

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
DroneCommands dc; 
dc.Land(3);

}
```

The command prompt error is: undefined reference to `DroneCommands::DroneCommands()'

Please let me know why this does not work even though I can get it to run on Xcode successfully. Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88811/unidentified-reference-issue-when-having-.h-and-.cpp-files/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-08**:
Is your header file located in the src folder or in include/?

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-09**:
Hey, it was in the src folder.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-09**:
Are you linking the both source files together? Please post your CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-09**:
I only did : rosbuild_add_executable(main src/main.cpp). So I need to add rosbuild_add_executable(DroneCommandssrc/DroneCommands.cpp) also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the following in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(main src/main.cpp DroneCommandssrc/DroneCommands.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-10**:
Brilliant, thanks!!

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-11**:
Hi, I tried: rosbuild_add_executable(main src/main.cpp DroneCommands src/X/DroneCommands.cpp)

The reason I have X is because my DroneCommands.cpp file is in a folder called X. Is it not possible to separate the .cpp files into different files because that seems to be the error.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-11**:
remove the DroneCommands only use: rosbuild_add_executable(main src/main.cpp  src/X/DroneCommands.cpp)

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-10-12**:
Thank you!